# Multiple EntityFactoryManager conflict

Tags: spring, spring-boot, grails, spring-data-jpa

I have a grails application. I need to access to different database applications. I have added both as dependencies. I have created two different `EntityManagerFactory` for each database as you can see below. But I am getting this exception

```
    ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:51)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:335)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:324)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at analyticsapplication.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:457)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:168)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsCacheFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#648b2d65' of type [grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.simple.MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter] while setting bean property 'filter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#648b2d65': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.setUrlMappingsHandlerMapping(org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsHandlerMapping); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsHandlerMapping': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsHandlerMapping.setWebRequestInterceptors(org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequestInterceptor[]); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactory,offersEntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:214)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:78)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:224)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:209)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5244)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#648b2d65': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.setUrlMappingsHandlerMapping(org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsHandlerMapping); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsHandlerMapping': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsHandlerMapping.setWebRequestInterceptors(org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequestInterceptor[]); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactory,offersEntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.setUrlMappingsHandlerMapping(org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsHandlerMapping); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsHandlerMapping': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsHandlerMapping.setWebRequestInterceptors(org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequestInterceptor[]); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactory,offersEntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:661)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsHandlerMapping': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsHandlerMapping.setWebRequestInterceptors(org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequestInterceptor[]); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactory,offersEntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsHandlerMapping.setWebRequestInterceptors(org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequestInterceptor[]); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactory,offersEntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:661)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactory,offersEntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactory,offersEntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:143)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.setBeanFactory(EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1565)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
INFO
```

My `resources.groovy` file

```
importBeans('classpath*:spring-config.xml')
importBeans('classpath*:spring-offers-data-access-config.xml')
```

My two database configuration files
`1`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>/spring-offers-data-access.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
    <!-- the base package for spring data jpa repository interfaces -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.asklytics.offers.dao.repos"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="offersEntityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="offersTransactionManager"/>

    <!-- Enable the component scan (auto wiring etc) for the following package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.asklytics.offers" />

    <!-- Make sure the following is specified to enable transaction  -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="offersTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="offersEntityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!--  This defines the entity manager factory with some custom properties -->
    <bean id='offersEntityManagerFactory' class='org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean'>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="offersPersistanceUnit"/>
        <property name='dataSource' ref='offersDatasource' />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.asklytics.offers" />
    </bean>

    <!--&lt;!&ndash; Create default configuration for Hibernate &ndash;&gt;
    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
    </bean>

    &lt;!&ndash; Configure the entity manager factory bean &ndash;&gt;
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        &lt;!&ndash; Set JPA properties &ndash;&gt;
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">none</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        &lt;!&ndash; Set base package of your entities &ndash;&gt;
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.asklytics.data.access"/>
        &lt;!&ndash; Set share cache mode &ndash;&gt;
        <property name="sharedCacheMode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE"/>
        &lt;!&ndash; Set validation mode &ndash;&gt;
        <property name="validationMode" value="NONE"/>
    </bean>-->

    <!-- This defines the hsqldb data source -->
    <!--
    <bean id='dataSource' class='org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource'>
        <property name='driverClassName' value='org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver' />
        <property name='url' value='jdbc:hsqldb:file:spring_jpa_test_db' />
        <property name='username' value='sa' />
        <property name='password' value='' />
    </bean>
     -->

    <bean id='offersDatasource' class='org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource'>
        <property name='driverClassName' value='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' />
        <property name='url' value="${offersDataAccessDbUrl}" />
        <property name='username' value="${offersDataAccessDbUsername}" />
        <property name='password' value="${offersDataAccessDbPassword}" />
    </bean>

    <!--&lt;!&ndash; flyway configuration &ndash;&gt;
    <bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" depends-on="dataSource" init-method="migrate">
           <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>-->

</beans>
```

`2nd file`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>/spring-data-access.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- the base package for spring data jpa repository interfaces -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.asklytics.dao.repos"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>

<!-- Enable the component scan (auto wiring etc) for the following package -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.asklytics.dao" />

<!-- Make sure the following is specified to enable transaction  -->
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<!--  This defines the entity manager factory with some custom properties -->
<bean id='entityManagerFactory' class='org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean'>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persitanceUnit"/>
    <property name='dataSource' ref='dataSource' />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.asklytics.dao" />
</bean>

<!--&lt;!&ndash; Create default configuration for Hibernate &ndash;&gt;
<bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
</bean>

&lt;!&ndash; Configure the entity manager factory bean &ndash;&gt;
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    &lt;!&ndash; Set JPA properties &ndash;&gt;
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    &lt;!&ndash; Set base package of your entities &ndash;&gt;
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.asklytics.data.access"/>
    &lt;!&ndash; Set share cache mode &ndash;&gt;
    <property name="sharedCacheMode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE"/>
    &lt;!&ndash; Set validation mode &ndash;&gt;
    <property name="validationMode" value="NONE"/>
</bean>-->

<!-- This defines the hsqldb data source -->
<!--
<bean id='dataSource' class='org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource'>
    <property name='driverClassName' value='org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver' />
    <property name='url' value='jdbc:hsqldb:file:spring_jpa_test_db' />
    <property name='username' value='sa' />
    <property name='password' value='' />
</bean>
 -->

<bean id='dataSource' class='org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource'>
    <property name='driverClassName' value='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' />
    <property name='url' value="${dataAccessDbUrl}" />
    <property name='username' value="${dataAccessDbUsername}" />
    <property name='password' value="${dataAccessDbPassword}" />
</bean>

<!--&lt;!&ndash; flyway configuration &ndash;&gt;
<bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" depends-on="dataSource" init-method="migrate">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>-->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare any of your entity factory as primary

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" primary="true" class='org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean'>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persitanceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.asklytics.dao" />
</bean>
```